# It is necessary to install Entity Framework package for Models and context which are in separate Class Library in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I created an Asp.net empty web Application and i installed Entity Framework package (from NuGet) for my web Application, and then i created two class Library (one for my Models and another for my Context), and then i put my models in separate Class Library and my Context too, but i couldn't access [dbContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.dbcontext%28v=vs.113%29.aspx) from my context Library. 
I want to know that i should install Entity Framework package for both of Library like my web Application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Entity Framework DLLs have to be added to the project with the context, but not the one with the models.